How to solve : UnknownError: Graph execution error:
i have 2.14 version of keras and tensorflow. My cuda version is :

I am trying to fit a simple model but I get the following exception :
UnknownError: Graph execution error:

The code is :
Problem_with_Graph_execution_error.py
My computer is a ubuntu 20.04 with a python 3.10.14 (ipython 8.27.0).
Please, any ideas or experiences that could help me.

You need to include the whole error message, not just one line.

Try adding the following lines of code:
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], enable=True)


Thank you very much. There are some interesting differences between version 2.14 and 2.15 of keras using anaconda
